# VNC into EC2 Ubuntu Instance

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I followed the guide [here](http://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/setting-up-vnc-on-ubuntu-in-the-amazon-ec2.html), and I seem to be able to connect but I get a blank screen using the Chicken VNC viewer. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I changed my `.vnc/xstartup` as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
unset SESSION_MANAGER
#exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
gnome-session --session=gnome-classic &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80×24+10+10 -ls -title “$VNCDESKTOP Desktop” &
#x-window-manager &
```